# Install Adobe Reader DC without uninstalling Adobe Reader?

Tags: mac, install, pdf, macos, adobe

How can I install the Adobe Reader DC without uninstalling the old Adobe Reader (11)?
I want to manage the installation of Adobe Reader DC on my clients without deleting their old Adobe Reader.
Is there a official download site from Adobe or could I edit the .pkg package?
I got a free Adobe Enterprise License also but I can only find the installer at Adobe which installs the DC but uninstalls the old Reader.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Acrobat (Pro) or Adobe/Acrobat Reader?

In the second case, you would not get the "official" download file from Adobe (because that is just a (IMHO extremely crappy) install manager. Instead you would get the actual Reader installer from the [enterprise page of the Adobe website](https://get.adobe.com/reader/enterprise/)

As you are on Mac, multiple versions can be installed in parallel, and even do run concurrently. Under Windows, neither is possible; all which is possible to install one version each of Reader and Acrobat, and preferably the same (Acrobat DC and Reader DC).

Comment: I am talking about the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and the Adobe Reader 1      I Just Need an Installer who installs the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC but don't uninstall the Adobe Reader 11 and i can't find any download for this on the Enterprise Site