# Can't install Adobe Acrobat Reader. "Found a higher version Adobe Acrobat Reader in the installation location."

Tags: pdf, adobe

A government client is sending me PDF documents that I can't read - Adobe Acrobat tells me I need a newer version of itself and gives me a link to the Adobe web site.

On my Windows laptop, I installed the latest version and I can read the document just fine.

But on our Mac laptop, the installation fails:

[image]

I tried moving the Adobe Acrobat Reader application to Trash and rebooting but I get the same error.

I tried installing the Adobe "clean" tool, but it says there is nothing installed.

Then I tried the installer again and it fails because there is a higher version present.

I found [How to clean uninstall Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221583/how-to-clean-uninstall-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc) from 2016, is it safe to try to follow these instructions on my 2020 MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6?

Or is there a better way?

I also looked at [Install Adobe Reader DC without uninstalling Adobe Reader?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281824/install-adobe-reader-dc-without-uninstalling-adobe-reader) but it says you can have multiple versions of Reader on the Mac which has definitely NOT been my experience.

I also moved to trash Adobe Bridge and rebooted, but the installer still bombs out.

Comment: Adobe uninstallers tend to be aliases inside each of Applications/Adobe [whatever name]/ and also in Applications/Utilities/Adobe Installers/ [which are also aliases, but have 'legible' names where the originals may not. After that it may depend on whether you have a full CC subscription or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tetsujin. There is nothing "Adobe" in my /Applications.  I also checked /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Installers/ where I found "Adobe Flash Player Install Manager.app/" which I deleted with "rm -rf".  Then I removed "/Library/Application Support/Adobe/".  Then I went to "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/" and removed "Adobe*".  Still no luck.

Comment: I installed Foxit Reader instead but when I opened the PDF I got the same message that I need a later version of Adobe Reader and the link to Adobe's website... pfftth!

Comment: Ha! I installed Adobe Acrobat DC Pro.  THAT installed fine.  What a PITA!